# How to parse a JSON with unknown key-value pairs in a Spark DataFrame to multiple rows of values

Tags: scala, dataframe

Input DataFrame is coming from Kafka in key value pair -

Input :

```
{
"CBT-POSTED-TXN": {
    "eventTyp": "TXN-NEW",
    "eventCatgry": "CBT-POSTED-TXN"
  },
  "CBT-BALANCE-CHG": {
    "eventTyp": "TXN-NEW",
    "eventCatgry": "CBT-BALANCE-CHG",
    "enablerEventVer": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

The output DataFrame needs to be -

ROW 1

```
{
    "eventTyp": "TXN-NEW",
    "eventCatgry": "CBT-POSTED-TXN"
}
```

ROW 2

```
{
    "eventTyp": "TXN-NEW",
    "eventCatgry": "CBT-BALANCE-CHG",
    "enablerEventVer": "1.0.0"
 }
```

Below is how i'm trying to parse -

```
override def translateSource(df: DataFrame, spark: SparkSession = SparkUtil.getSparkSession("")): DataFrame = {
    import spark.implicits._
    val k3ProcessingSchema: StructType = Encoders.product[k3SourceSchema].schema

    val dfTranslated=df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING) key", "cast(value as string) value", "CAST(partition as String)", "CAST(offset as String)", "CAST(timestamp as String)").as[(String, String, String, String, String)]
      .select(from_json($"value", k3ProcessingSchema).as("k3Clubbed"), $"value", $"key", $"partition", $"offset", $"timestamp")
      .select($"k3Clubbed", $"value", $"key", $"partition", $"offset", $"timestamp").filter("k3Clubbed is not null")
      .as[(k3SourceSchema, String, String, String, String, String)]

    dfTranslated.collect()




    df
  }

case class k3SourceSchema (
                          k3SourceValue: Map[String,String]
                          )
```

However the code is not able to parse the df(value) column which contains the JSON Format with multiple events into a map of String (key) and String (Value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about manipulating rows of a data frame and outputting multiple rows. The best way I see it is by using explode function over data frame but you would like to enrich your data in a format where you can use the explode function.

Refer the below code for better understanding -

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import java.util.HashMap
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
import com.lbg.pas.alerts.realtime.notifications.common.entity.K3FLDEntity

def translateSource(df: DataFrame, spark: SparkSession = SparkUtil.getSparkSession("")): DataFrame = {
    import spark.implicits._

    val dataSetSource = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING) key", "cast(value as string) value", "CAST(partition as String)", "CAST(offset as String)", "CAST(timestamp as String)")
      .select( $"value", $"key", $"partition", $"offset", $"timestamp").as[(String, String, String, String, String)]


      val dataSetTranslated = dataSetSource.map(row=>{
        val jsonInput= row._1
        val key = row._2
        val partition = row._3
        val offset = row._4
        val timestamp = row._5

        //Converting Original JSON to ArrayBuffer of JSON(s)
        val mapperObj = new ObjectMapper()
        val jsonMap = mapperObj.readValue(jsonInput,classOf[HashMap[String,HashMap[String,String]]])
        val JsonList = new ArrayBuffer[String]()

        for ((k,v) <- jsonMap.asScala){
          val jsonResp = mapperObj.writeValueAsString(v)
          JsonList+=jsonResp
        }
        K3FLDEntity(JsonList,key,partition,offset,timestamp)
      }).as[(ArrayBuffer[String],String,String,String,String)]

    val dataFrameTranslated=dataSetTranslated.withColumn("value",explode($"JsonList"))
      .drop("JsonList")
      .toDF()

    dataFrameTranslated
  }
```

I am using the below case class -

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

case class K3FLDEntity(
                        JsonList : ArrayBuffer[String],
                        key: String,
                        partition: String,
                        offset: String,
                        timestamp:String
                      )
```